# Python xmpp jabber client in tornado web application

Tags: python, xmpp, tornado

I am desktop programmer but I want to learn something about web services. I decided for python. I am trying understand how web applications works. I know how to create basic tornado website (request - response) and working jabber client, but I don't know how to mix them. Can I use any python components in web services? Does they must have specific structure ( sync or async )? Because I'm stuck in loop handlers:

If tornado start web serwer by command:

```
app = Application()
app.listen(options.port)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

... so how (where) can I start xmpp loop?

```
client.connect()
client.run()
```

I think that tornado listen loop should handle xmpp listening, but don't know how

Regards.

**Edit:** I forgot. I am using pyxmpp2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to accomplish is not feasible in one thread of python as both are trying to listen at the same time which isn't possible in one thread. Might I suggest looking at [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/) tutorial on threading.

Another question would be are you trying to make a web based xmpp or just have a xmpp & html server running in the same script. If you wish to try the former I would advise you to look into inter-thread communication either with [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) or [queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html)

Comment: I'm trying to create web based xmpp client. Thanks for links

Comment: When I'm trying to run xmpp loop in thread I get error: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'serializer'

Comment: update your question with the exact code that you are having trouble with and I will help you fix it

Comment: It seems that pyxmpp2 has trouble working in threads. So I tried with xmppy and works fine (I can run tornado server and connect to xmpp server). Xmppy need infinite loop created by programmer to handle connection and this is exactly what I needed. So my major question about "mixing" is solved and rest problems will be posted in another topics ;) Thanks

Comment: No problem :] Glad to be of assistance :D

Answer (score 0):

maybe WebSocketHandler and Thread will help you.

Demo

```
class BotThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,my_jid,settings,on_message):
        super(BotThread,self).__init__()
        #EchoBot is pyxmpp2's Client
        self.bot = EchoBot(my_jid, settings,on_message= on_message)

    def run(self):
        self.bot.run()


class ChatSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self): 
        #init xmpp client
        my_jid = 
        settings = 
        bot =BotThread(my_jid, settings,on_message=self.on_message)
        bot.start()
```